# Solving Dyck's path with a cost function.

Tags: combinatorics

Given the cost function,
where T is any valid dyck's path from $(0,0)\to(2n,0)$ and $M(n)$ is the set of all valid paths from $(0,0)\to(2n,0)$ each step is of $(+1,+1)$ or $(+1,-1)$ and it never goes below x axis.

> Find $\underset{T \in M(n)}{\sum}\phi(T)$, where $\phi(T)  = \overset{2n}{\underset{i=1}{\Pi}}\mu_i$, where $\mu_i$ is given by
> \begin{equation}
>     \mu_i = 
>     \begin{cases}
>       1 & i^{th}\text{ step is } (x,y) \to (x+1,y+1)\\
>       y & i^{th}\text{ step is } (x,y) \to (x+1,y-1)\\
>     \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

I know that final answer comes out to be $\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\Pi}}(2i-1)$, via forming a recurrence relation of

> $$f(i,j) = (j+1)f(i-1,j+1)+f(i+1,j-1)$$

and simulating it on for various values, but I want a mathematically valid proof for it. I had also tried to derive a generating function for this recurrence relation, and it came out to be,

> $$f(x,y) = e^{\frac{y}{x}-\frac{y^2}{2}}$$

but expanding its terms at $(0,0)$ using Taylor Series doesn't give correct result since division by $0$ is not allowed.